# Parser: Compilation error[not found: value get]

Tags: scala, anorm

When I create a parser for the output of Anorm.SQL I get the following error: `Parser: Compilation error[not found: value get]`

```
val parser = {
  get[String]("id") ~
  get[String]("name") map { ... }
}
```

Likewise the following code returns `Parser: Compilation error[not found: value str]`

```
val parser = {
  str("id") ~
  str("name") map { ... }
}
```

Same for `Parser: Compilation error[not found: value int]`

Comment: Most of the code examples of official doc mentions either the imports or `SqlParser.` prefix: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm

Comment: Yes, I re-read the doc but I wanted to ask the question on Stackoverflow as it took me a while to find the solution. Indeed, the real solution is to read  the manual. Also thanks for the down vote, this may not be useful to you but it'd have been useful to me if that question had existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely to be namespace-related. You probably are trying to build a SQL query and already imported `anorm._` however `get`, `str`, `int` and more are available under `SqlParser` namespace.

You can either import the parser `SqlParser` at the top of your file:

```
 import anorm.SqlParser._
```

Or call directly like the following:

```
 import anorm._     

 // ...

 val parser = {
   SqlParser.get[String]("id") ~
   SqlParser.get[String]("name") map { ... }
 }

 // or

 val parser = {
   SqlParser.str("id") ~
   SqlParser.str("name") map { ... }
 }
```